# Python: Removing the element in a list while looping the list

Tags: python, list

Here is a simple question. My task is to loop a list and print each element it has. After each printing, I intend to delete this element from the list as well. My code is:

```
>> a = [1,2]
>> for x in a:
>>   print x
>>   a.remove(x)
>>   print a
```

The output is:

```
>> 1
>> [2]
```

However, something strange happens here:
Only 1 has been printed and it seems after removing 1 from the list, the program jumps out of loop directly. My assumption is after changing the content of the list, the iterator may also be affected, but I'm not very sure. A more safe way is:

```
>> a = [1,2]
>> b = list(a)
>> for x in b:
>>   print x
>>   a.remove(x)
>>   print a
```

Could someone please provide me any more advanced explanation?

Comment: The iterator tracks the position, yes. But why would you bother removing each element? You'll end up with an empty list.

Comment: `b = list(a)` creates a copy of the list, so `a` and `b` become different objects. [This](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/) might be useful.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34238688/8747) has a decent explanation.

Comment: If you want to iterate over a list while modyfying it, use a `while` loop or make a copy of the list for a `for` loop.

Comment: visualize your code - http://www.codeskulptor.org/viz/

Comment: just by curious haha and want to figure out how python for-loop works. Is it like Java's `for(Element e: list)` and C#'s `foreach`? Each time the iterator call `has_next()` and if negative, the loop will terminate.

Comment: The for-statement will ask the iterable for an iterator `iter(a)` and keep asking that iterator for next value `next(iterator)` until there's an exception marking the end which the for-statement catches and stops looping

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1,2]
while a:
    print a.pop(0)
    print a
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove elements from a list that you are iterating over with `for`.

Your guess is close -- you can see more clearly what's happening if you use a longer list:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
for x in a:
    print x
    a.remove(x)
    print a
```

output:

```
1
[2, 3, 4, 5]
3
[2, 4, 5]
5
[2, 4]
```

It prints the element at index 0, then index 1, then index 2... and by then there is no index 3.

In your example it prints the element at index 1, then there is no index 2.